Count NULL values by row in BQ
I am new to BQ and i was wondering if there is a way to create a column which has the amount of columns with NULL value by row.
For example if I have this table in big query and the column I want to create is the number 4 which contains how many NULL values have the first 3 columns.
Thanks if you take the time to leave an answer.


Use below generic approach (BigQuery)
select *,
  array_length(regexp_extract_all(translate(format('%t', t), ', ()', r'||||'), r'\|NULL\|')) null_count
from your_table t   

if applied to sample data in your question - output is


What about something like:
SELECT *, IF(COLUMN_1 IS NULL, 1, 0) +
IF(COLUMN_2 IS NULL, 1, 0) +
IF(COLUMN_3 IS NULL, 1, 0) AS COLUMN_4
FROM <TABLE>

If we want something dynamic, we can try:
create temp function count_nulls(row JSON)
returns int64
language js
as r"""
let count = 0;
for (key in row) {
  if (row[key] === null) {
    count = count + 1
  }
}
return count;
""";

select *, count_nulls(t) as column_4 from <yourTable> as t;

